# Gmap jquery android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, dictionary

I'm using Phonegap + JQueryMobile + JQuery to create a map inside my index.html. There's a problem, in the browser my code works fine but when I try to run on my phone then not shows the map.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#map").gmap();
    });
</script>
</head> <body><div id="map" style="height: 350px; width: 600px"></div></body></html>
```

I think that the the errors are on the script sources because i need to import the correct gmap for phones but i don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: can you also share the logs from logcat? sometimes if there are errors you should find more information in it.

Comment: No because it's all HTML5 code, the logcat only shows errors on Java code i think :)

Comment: when using phonegap, it is will trap any javascript errors and post in logcat, the messages might not be detailed but atleast would give you a way point to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled internet access in AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```